# smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError when sending mail though outlook using python

Tags: python, outlook

I am trying to send emails to certain people in my organization I have an ongoing communication with. The user name and password I am entering are correct. I keep getting this error:

smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your administrator. [SJ0PR05CA0165.namprd05.prod.outlook.com]')

I am the administrator, it's a small company.

```
import openpyxl, smtplib, sys
    
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('testemailpop.xlsx')
sheet = wb["Sheet1"]
lastCol = sheet.max_column
latestMessage = sheet.cell(row=1, column=lastCol).value

unmessagedMembers = {}
for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    message = sheet.cell(row=r, column=lastCol).value
    if message != 'Messaged':
        name = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
        email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
        unmessagedMembers[name] = email

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('me@company.com', sys.argv[1])

for name, email in unmessagedMembers.items():
    body = "Subject: Company\nHello,\nThis is a test message. Please respond Thank you!'"
    print('Sending email to %s...' % email)
    sendmailStatus = smtpObj.sendmail('me@company.com', email,
body)

    if sendmailStatus != {}:
        print('There was a problem sending email to %s: %s' % (email,
           sendmailStatus))
smtpObj.quit()
```

Comment: That erros is given, when your connection to ur sending email, isnt sucessfull. Meaning that the security paremeters are maybe not correct, or you havent changed ur security, acesses so you are not capable to connecting to it

Answer (score 0):

You did **not** login with your **sender** mail successfully as said before. Check  security settings of your sender mail or sys.argv[1] is correct password for your sender mail. May be some unicode problem can be exist in password, idk? If you are sure everything is okay, may be you can use  different library like that: https://github.com/O365/python-o365 . But it is obvious that it will not work anyway if login connection data are not correct.